# Error when running the command line "npm run dev" in a vite project of the latest versions

Tags: node.js, module, vite, cjs

The problem does not occur only when using Vite version 4.4.1.

When running "npm run dev", the following happens...

```
PS C:\Users\user\desktop\vite-project> npm run dev

> vite-project@0.0.0 dev
> vite

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\user\Desktop\vite-project\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\vite-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:60:48)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v21.2.0
```

The following is a complete overview...

```
PS C:\Users\user> cd desktop
PS C:\Users\user\desktop> npm create vite@latest
√ Project name: ... vite-project
√ Select a framework: » React
√ Select a variant: » TypeScript

Scaffolding project in C:\Users\user\Desktop\vite-project...

Done. Now run:

  cd vite-project
  npm install
  npm run dev

PS C:\Users\user\desktop> cd vite-project
PS C:\Users\user\desktop\vite-project> npm install

added 209 packages, and audited 210 packages in 23s

40 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\user\desktop\vite-project> npm run dev

> vite-project@0.0.0 dev
> vite

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\user\Desktop\vite-project\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\vite-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:60:48)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v21.2.0
```

package.json...

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

I tried it in several versions of Node including 21, 20, 18, and 16. But with none of them, the error disappears. Also tried with pnpm but it didn't work either. I tried resetting my computer but that didn't fix the error either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in React vite project due to rollup dependency (module not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569907/error-in-react-vite-project-due-to-rollup-dependency-module-not-found)